# How is it possible to share a static variable between functions?

Tags: rust, static-variables, variable-declaration

I'm trying to define a static variable within a function `f0` and re-use it within another function `f1`.

```
fn f0() {
    static v: i32 = 10;
}

fn f1() {
    static v: i32; // the compiler reports a syntax error for this statement
}
```

However, because it wasn't assigned to any value in the second function, the compiler reported an error saying:

> expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `::`, `<`, or `=`, found `;`

I'm using nightly Rust toolchain: **rustc 1.40.0-nightly**.

This sounds little odd, since declaring a static variable doesn't require value assignment by nature.

What's supposed to cause the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a static mutable variable without assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145814/how-do-i-declare-a-static-mutable-variable-without-assignment)

Comment: You need to make the variable global. If you declare it within a function, it is accessible only by that function by design.

Comment: @SCappella It's not the same case, because what I'm looking for is using the same variable in two functions.

Comment: @mcarton Thanks for the tip. Using lazy_static helped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare static variables that are not initialized, because the Rust compiler assumes that all variables are initialized.

If you really want to do it, you will want to use [`std::mem::MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html).

However, even if you did that, it wouldn't solve your original issue (sharing a static variable between functions). Each static in your example is independent of each other.

Therefore, you will need to make a global static variable.

Comment: What he really wants is to share the static variable between two functions.

Comment: @mcarton Yes, that is the X of the XY, but I answered the actual question posted in the title, the Y. I added a clarification.